# Is there a concept that relates to the idea of a "snuck premise"?

Tags: logic, fallacies

In this video around 6:00 into it,

Charisma on Command channel, "7 Reasons Ben Shapiro Is So Dominant in Debates" 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JY5t6iUzajk

the concept of a "snuck premise" is introduced.

Does anyone know if there is a concept in philosophy like this? I was trying to find the concept online, but it doesn't seem that it is a formal term.

Comment: [Unwarranted assumption](https://gradestack.com/MCAT-Complete-Tutor/Inductive-Arguments/Unwarranted-Assumptions-/17294-3351-19765-study-wtw)?

Comment: This seems like a rhetorical technique. Interesting video. And welcome to this SE!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires reference to an outside source, and does not give a self-contained question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote that is supposed to contain a "snuck premise" is the following ([about 6:20-6:29](https://youtu.be/JY5t6iUzajk?t=381)):

> As you may have noticed I'm mostly against abortion. If you want to go to Planned Parenthood to get a contraceptive, go for it. I don't care. I do care when you start killing babies."

The "killing babies" is referred to as the "snuck premise", an introduction of the point of contention as a given.

This may be seen as a kind of red herring. I imagine he redirected the focus of the argument from something else to the phrase "killing babies".

Here are some synonyms for red herring on the [Logically Fallacious site](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/150/Red-Herring):

> beside the point, misdirection [form of], changing the subject, false emphasis, the Chewbacca defense, irrelevant conclusion, irrelevant thesis, clouding the issue, ignorance of refutation

This might work as a description of this rhetorical technique if his opponents felt distracted by having to defend against his claim of "killing babies".

However, it is also possible that they were discussing abortion and he was just reiterating his position as a given. That would also be a rhetorical technique perhaps related to "[argument by repetition](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/49/Argument-by-Repetition)".

---

Reference

Charisma on Command channel, "7 Reasons Ben Shapiro Is So Dominant in Debates" https://youtu.be/JY5t6iUzajk?t=381

"Argument by Repetition" Logically Fallacious https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/49/Argument-by-Repetition

"Red Herring" Logically Fallacious https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/150/Red-Herring

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, especially the included references to www.logicallyfallacious.com !

Answer (score 0):

It seems the snuck premise is a concept entered as a valid argument that is beyond question and then the speaker moves on, kind of like begging the question only on steroids.

Using "abortion is baby killing" is a provacative thesis that is going to have to use lots of evidence; it cannot stand on its own.

Comment: Would you have a reference to this concept? I think the OP wants to know "if there is a concept in philosophy like this?"